# Search and replace a word within a line, and print the result in next line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that contains this line in multiples:

```
Wait(0.000005);
```

The objective is make a search/replace function to convert into this format:

```
//Wait(0.000005);

Wait(5);
```

The first part of commenting off the "Wait(0.000005);" is done.
Having difficulty with the replacement from the first line.

Could someone please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: what is the relationship between `0.000005` and `50`?

Comment: What do you mean by the first part and the second part?

Comment: @Ian
Its a conversion from nano-second to mili-seconds. It depends on the source input, and the output will always be in mili-seconds.

Comment: @piglet
I wrote a simple 2 lines of code to comment off the original "Wait(0.000005)" line

Comment: Then, should it not be from `0.000005` to `5`? Since milliseconds to nano-seconds is `x10^6`

Comment: Ah yes, another mistake spotted, thanks !

Comment: @user6027952 OK, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner to do the substitution at the command line using sed:

```
sed 's/Wait(0.000005);/ \/\/Wait(0.000005);\'$'\nWait(50);/' filename.py
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"^.*Wait(0.000005);.*$", re.IGNORECASE)
for line in some_file:
    line = regex.sub("^.*Wait(0.000005);.*$","Wait(50);", line)
```

This might be a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can come in very handy here:

```
import re                    

with open("example.txt") as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()

pattern = re.compile("Wait\(([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)\)")

for line in data:
    matches = pattern.match(line)
    if matches:
        value = float(matches.group(1))
        newLine = "//" + matches.group(0) + "\n\n"
        newLine += "Wait(%i)" % (value * 10000000)
        print newLine
    else:
        print line
```

Example input:

```
Wait(0.000005);
Wait(0.000010);

Wait(0.000005);
```

Example output:

```
//Wait(0.000005)

Wait(50)
//Wait(0.000010)

Wait(100)


//Wait(0.000005)

Wait(50)
```